# Serve images as webp if browser support

Tags: images, optimization

I want to serve webp images if the browser support as Google Page Speed is asking me to serve images in next-gen format ,
I am looking for a solution without using any plugin :

I have found some code snippets that may be helpful :

Convert Image to webp format :

```
<?php

// Image
$dir = 'img/countries/';
$name = 'brazil.png';
$newName = 'brazil.webp';

// Create and save
$img = imagecreatefrompng($dir . $name);
imagepalettetotruecolor($img);
imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagewebp($img, $dir . $newName, 100);
imagedestroy($img);
```

From Php Official Documentation

I have also found this code for optimization that might be useful

```
/**
 * B) Modify the quality of original jpeg images to 90, during uploads
 */
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', function( $metadata, $attachment_id )
{
    $file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
    $type = get_post_mime_type( $attachment_id );

    // Target jpeg images
    if( in_array( $type, [ 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg' ] ) )
    {
        // Check for a valid image editor
        $editor = wp_get_image_editor( $file );
        if( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) )
        {
            // Set the new image quality
            $result = $editor->set_quality( 90 );

            // Re-save the original image file
            if( ! is_wp_error( $result ) )
                $editor->save( $file );
        }
    }
    return $metadata;
}, 10, 2 );
```

I have googled about this a lot but I have found only solutions based on plugins .
Do anyone has any idea about that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the resistance to using plugins? It’s code that someone else has written and tested for you.

Comment: What mechanism do you want to use to show webps when available? Does it need client or server implementation? (If you’re substituting images in tags that’ll have to be done client side of your site has caching)

Comment: function webpsupport()
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp') !== false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Free plugins are always having limitations